# Write to CLOB in Java

Tags: java

Now we are using the following code to write the data into the .csv file ( i.e for creating)

But Now I have to update this data directly to the one database column CLOB.
without generating any .csv file.

How can I add this data to CLOB.
here we r passing each and every line as vector to the writeIT() and it is adding that to filewriter.

what I should do to write it in CLOB?
Please Help me out..

```
writeIt(mlh);
<Loop>
writeIt(row);
<End Loop>
writeIt(null);
writeIt(commentLineHeader);
<Loop>
writeIt(row);
<End Loop>

protected void writeIt (Vector a){

 if (filewriter==null) return;
    try {

      if (a!=null){
        for (int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
          //Object o=a.elementAt(i);
            Object o=a.elementAt(i);
          if (o!=null) {
              String str=o.toString();
              // replacing an komma inside a string with a point.
              str = str.replace(',','.');
              // replacing a new line in hexa it's 0A and 0F with blank
              str = str.replace('\n',' '); // LF replace
              str = str.replace('\r',' '); // CR replace
              filewriter.write(str);



          }
              if (i!=a.size()-1) filewriter.write(",");

          }
      }

    }
    catch (IOException e){
      errH.addMessage(L_ERROR,"_$EXCEPTION_RAISED -" + e.toString());

      PAVSessionManager.getInstance().update_in_use_flag();

    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Clob object, by calling `connection.createClob()` and then call `clob.setCharacterStream(int)` to get reference to a `Writer` object, then just writer your content to the Writer, that's it.